# smtp error 421 4.4.2 Error: timeout exceeded after few minutes and some bytes received - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: postfix, smtp, telnet

I get the following error while trying to send the email using telnet from the client xxxx-01 with the mail body exceeding certain amount of text. The same length of the body works fine on the remaining two hosts xxxx-02 & 03 to the same relay host without any issues. The target relay host runs on RHEL 6 and postfix 2.6. TCP DUMP does not indicate any problem on the target host / client.

The TCP window scaling is enabled on both target and client hosts, so I do not think we really need to disable it as its working fine on the other clients.

The email with lesser text works absolutely fine from xxxx-01 > target relay host.

Error message:

```
smtp error 421 4.4.2 Error: timeout exceeded after 5 minutes
```

3 clients and their kernel version (Ubuntu)

```
root@xxxx-02:~# uname -r
4.4.0-63-generic

root@xxxx-03:~# uname -r
4.4.0-59-generic
```

Not working Client:

```
root@xxxx-01:~# uname -r
4.4.0-64-generic
```

Error log on the mail relay host which is running postfix 2.6 and RHEL6:

```
2017-04-12T18:56:40.999543-05:00 840439-abc8 postfix/smtpd[8865]: connect from unknown[172.24.32.6]
2017-04-12T18:56:41.010133-05:00 840439-abc8 postfix/smtpd[8865]: 02717B0093E: client=unknown[172.24.32.6]
2017-04-12T18:57:05.481704-05:00 840439-abc8 postfix/smtpd[10309]: connect from unknown[172.24.32.6]
2017-04-12T18:57:32.091900-05:00 840439-abc8 postfix/smtpd[10309]: 16678B009B1: client=unknown[172.24.32.6]
2017-04-12T19:01:41.112792-05:00 840439-abc8 postfix/smtpd[8865]: timeout after DATA (0 bytes) from unknown[172.24.32.6]
2017-04-12T19:01:41.112811-05:00 840439-abc8 postfix/smtpd[8865]: disconnect from unknown[172.24.32.6]
2017-04-12T19:03:12.218402-05:00 840439-abc8 postfix/smtpd[10309]: timeout after DATA (30 bytes) from unknown[172.24.32.6]
2017-04-12T19:03:12.218421-05:00 840439-abc8 postfix/smtpd[10309]: disconnect from unknown[172.24.32.6]
```

Telnet from the client

```
ops@xxxx-01:~$ telnet mail8.xyz.com 25
Trying 192.168.203.205...
Connected to mail8.xyz.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail8.xyz.com ESMTP Postfix
EHLO 72.xx.xx.xx
250-mail8.xyz.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 9900000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
MAIL FROM: noreply@xyz.com
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO: abc.xyz@xyz.com
250 2.1.5 Ok
DATA
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Subject: Some Feed Results: SomeFeedserviceFeedService - xxxx-01
01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 90123*100* 01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 90123*200* 01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 90123*300* 01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 90123*400* 01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 90123*500* 01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 90123*600* 01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 90123*700* 01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 90123*800* 01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 90123*900* 01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 9012*1000* 01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 90123*100* 01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 90123*200* 01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 90123*300* 01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 90123456
.
421 4.4.2 mail8.xyz.com Error: timeout exceeded
Connection closed by foreign host.
ops@xxxx-01:~$
```

It works fine if I remove some digits from the end of mail body

```
ops@xxxx-01:~$ telnet mail8.xyz.com 25
Trying 192.168.203.205...
Connected to mail8.xyz.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail8.xyz.com ESMTP Postfix
EHLO 72.xx.xx.xx
250-mail8.xyz.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 9900000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
MAIL FROM: noreply@xyz.com
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO: abc.xyz@xyz.com
250 2.1.5 Ok
DATA
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Subject: Some Feed Results: SomeFeedserviceFeedService - xxxx-01
01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 90123*100* 01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 90123*200* 01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 90123*300* 01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 90123*400* 01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 90123*500* 01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 90123*600* 01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 90123*700* 01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 90123*800* 01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 90123*900* 01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 9012*1000* 01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 90123*100* 01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 90123*200* 01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 90123*300* 01234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 901234567 9012345
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 87871B01839
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
```

So the question is why it fails only from one of the clients? it timeouts approx after few minutes only on the client "xxxx-01". The only difference between those three clients is minor difference in the kernel version but I do not believe it's the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

first of all to understand the SMTP in depth, i hope u find this helpful:
http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1123/109.htm
the 5 minutes are generated of a 2 minutes after the data injection initiation plus 3 minutes for the data block. both of these contribute in the 5 minutes

since you tired to send smaller message size, then obviously the issue is being triggered  by the size of the message.

for that you have 2 paths to think about:

first, the message is too large with a fragment flag set to 0 and the ICMPv4 is blocked on either your firewall or the destination firewall or other security device. 
this means that the 2 sides (sender, recipient) cant agree on the MTU which means on other words, the size is not acceptable during the SMTP handshake.

second option, the recipient might have a certain mail policies limiting certain size (throttling).